"Test deployments" -> "Create new test" doesn't work in AppsScript Project for Docs Addon
I've been added to an existing Google App Script project which is deployed as an Editor add-on. It's been deployed and is available to users so it has a custom project backing it, not the default. I've made a change to the script and I now want to create a new test so that I can ensure the fix is working before I publish it. I created a new fixed version
I followed the instructions here very carefully: https://developers.google.com/workspace/add-ons/how-tos/testing-editor-addons
I hit "Create new test", I enter all the details. I hit "Save" and it opens a spinner, and says "Saving". Then once the spinner goes away, it returns to an empty screen saying "This project doesn't have any configured tests yet".
No errors. No messages. Nothing. It just doesn't create a new test. I've tried on a project of my own and it works perfectly there. But my personal project hasn't been deployed so it's still using the default project. That's the only difference I can find. But I'm listed with the owner role in the IAM of that project, the same as the original developer. So I'm not sure if it's a permission, a setting, or what it is.
Note: It's only the test that I'm unable to create. I can create deployments, I can edit them. It's all fine except tests, for some reason.

Please ensure that you own the Google Apps Script project or, if the project is owned by someone else, that it's stored in a Share Drive.
Reference

Collaborate with other developers

Related

How to test an editor add-on for Google Docs with the new Apps Script editor?


Thanks, but the project is on a shared drive and I have "editor" permissions. I have the "owner" role on the cloud project to which the Apps Script project links.
